# Authentication between two Micro Service in PCF

Tags: .net-core, microservices, pcf

Is there a way to ensure that serviceA is called only by serviceB(or a set of whitelisted services)? All the services are independent and do not go through a service gateway as they are completely independent.

Are there any good microservice patterns to follow up on this?

Answer (score 0):

If possible, use [RFC 6749, 4.4. Client Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4) also known as [Client Credentials Flow](https://medium.com/@darutk/diagrams-and-movies-of-all-the-oauth-2-0-flows-194f3c3ade85) or [Machine-to-Machine (M2M) flow](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/concepts/m2m-flow).

1. Define a meaningful scope ideally related to the [bounded context](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html) of serviceB. For example, if serviceB has user management functionality, it could be something like `user:read`;
2. [serviceA request an access token](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/guides/m2m-flow/call-api-using-m2m-flow#request-token) by [passing scope as an optional argument](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4)
3. based on the scope and api client identifier / secret of serviceA, auth service grant (or not) an access token
4. serviceA makes a call to serviceB with an access token. [ServiceB verify if access token is valid and has the intended scope](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/aspnet-core-webapi)

Keep in mind that there are other ways to accomplish this (at network level by whitelisted IPs for example) but OAUTH2 is the industry-standard protocol for authorization and I guess that [RFC 6749, 4.4. Client Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4) cover your need.